# React Native hangs forever

Tags: javascript, android, ios, mobile, react-native

I have an issue trying installing a new project for React-Native. It hangs with this:

```
react-native@0.33.0` requires a peer of react@~15.3.1 but none was installed.
npm verb exit [ 0, true ]
npm info ok
```

And It stay like that forever.

```
npm 3.10.7
node 6.2.1
```

Comment: react native have `peerDependencies` of `react@~15.3.1`. check if it is available on your system.

Comment: Yes! It's available, I installed it in my project and ran again the init command but still it doesn't create android/ios folders etc...

Comment: I've been with this and tried different ways.
It always stay at 

`Awesomep@0.0.1 /Users/jfernandez/projects/Awesomep
└── react@15.3.1  extraneous

npm verb exit [ 0, true ]
npm info ok`

Answer (score 3):

I also ran into this issue and can confirm that the problem is watchman.  I had used homebrew to uninstall/reinstall and was still running into the same issues.  My steps to solve were the following:

- Uninstall watchman with homebrew
- Delete the contents of the `/usr/local/var/run/watchman/` folder
- Re-install watchman with homebrew

I was able to figure out the extra step of deleting the contents of the watchman folder from these two github issues:
 - https://github.com/facebook/watchman/issues/361
 - https://github.com/facebook/watchman/issues/358#issuecomment-246672605

Comment: my saviour! it's so strange how this problem randomly popped up after my MacBook crashed and refused to go away even with `watchman watch-del-all`

Answer (score 0):

After few days going around, the problem was Watchman, Uninstalled and re-installed again did the work.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following steps:

1. Remove the current watcher: `watchman watch-del-all`
2. Delete your `node_modules` folder
3. Run `npm cache clean -f`
4. Run `npm install`

Check if your react native project can run with your simulator now: 
react-native run-ios